# Latex command exists check condition

Tags: macros, conditionals

How to check condition if `\commandtwo` presented in the tex file `\commandone` `\if` condition should be process otherwise `\else`  condition should be process? How to make a condition?

Note: `\commandtwo{XXX}` may or may not present in the tex file that is after `\begin{document}`, but definitions of `\def\commandone#1{#1}`, `\def\commandtwo#1{#1}` and `\def\commandthree#1{#1}` in the preamble.

MWE file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
%\commandtwo present in the file \if condition should be process if not presented in the file \else condition should be process
\def\commandone#1{\ifx\@ScndArg\@empty{\Huge#1}\else{\tiny#1}\fi}

\def\commandtwo#1{\def\@ScndArg{#1}#1}

\def\commandthree#1{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\commandone{AAA}

\commandtwo{BBB}

\commandthree{CCC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, only a condition \commondtwo{xx} presented after the \begin{document} Pointsize need to be updated within \def\commnadone#1{#1} macros.

Comment: \commandtwo presented \def\commandone#1{\tiny#1} otherwise \def\commandone#1{\Huge#1}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `\commandtwo` could appear *after* `\commandone`, you need to consider using the `.aux` for storing content that will be used in a secondary compilation. Below `\commandtwo` writes `\gdef\commandtwopresent{}` into the `.aux` that will be read upon the next compilation. Even though it's defined to be nothing, it can be used to condition via `\ifcsname`...`\endcsname`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%\commandtwo present in the file \if condition should be process if not presented in the file \else condition should be process
\def\commandone#1{\ifcsname commandtwopresent\endcsname {\Huge#1}\else{\tiny#1}\fi}

\def\commandtwo#1{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\commandtwopresent{}}%
  #1}

\def\commandthree#1{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\commandone{AAA}

\commandtwo{BBB}

\commandthree{CCC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, Thank you Werner.

Answer (score 1):

[Werner suggested defining a macro via the .aux-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576298), the macro being defined indicating whether in the previous LaTeX-run `\commandtwo` was carried out.

Following this suggestion, I offer a variant where instead a cross-referencing label is written which yields either "true" or "false" and which can be used in a `\csname..\endcsname` expression that yields either `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`.

An advantage of this variant is that you are informed via the console and the .log-file if you have to recompile because something has changed, because the change is accompanied by the change of said cross-referencing label while changes of cross-referencing labels are tracked by the LaTeX kernel.

A disadvantage of this variant is that an additional package, the package [atveryend](https://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend), is needed for hooking in at the right moment in time for writing the said cross-referencing label.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{atveryend}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{CommandTwoUsed}{\CommandTwoUsed}}%
}%
\newcommand\CommandTwoUsed{false}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\newcommand
  \expandafter\CheckWhetherCommandTwoUsed
  \expandafter{%
    \csname if\@ifundefined{r@CommandTwoUsed}{false}{\r@CommandTwoUsed}\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  }%
}%
\newcommand\commandtwo[1]{\gdef\CommandTwoUsed{true}#1}
\newcommand\commandone[1]{\CheckWhetherCommandTwoUsed{{\Huge#1}}{{\tiny#1}}}
\newcommand\commandthree[1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\commandone{AAA}

\commandtwo{BBB}

\commandthree{CCC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does "present" mean in the phrase "`\commandtwo` present in the file"?

Assume the .tex-input-file in question (or some other file processed via `\input` or `\include`, belonging to the document in question?) contains
`\verb|\commandtwo...|`
and/or
 `% This is a comment containing \commandtwo`.

Would the condition of `\commandtwo` being present in the file be fulfilled in this case?

If you only wish to know whether `\commandtwo` was already carried out/was not(yet) carried out while assuming that there are no other ways of defining `\@ScndArg` but carrying out `\commandtwo`, then you can check if `\@ScndArg` is defined/is undefined.

Werner already showed in his answer how to do this via `\ifcsname..\endcsname` in case ε-TeX-extensions are available.

For the sake of having fun you can implement testing whether a macro argument has a first token which is a control sequence which is undefined by checking whether the `\meaning` of that token contains the phrase "undefined". This way it is not needed to rely on the availability of whatsoever TeX-extension:

```
\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange,  \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument has a first token which is an
%% undefined control sequence.
%% (Only with undefined control sequences the \meaning has the leading phrase
%% "undefined"; besides this \meaning never delivers no tokens at all)
%%.............................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                 which is to be checked> has a 1st token 
%%                                 which is undefined>}%
%%                              {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                which is to be checked> does not have a 1st
%%                                token which is undefined>}%
\begingroup
\def\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined#1{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined[1]{%
    \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
    \string##1X}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
    \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
       % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
       % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
       \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
         \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
         \string{\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingUndefinedB\expandafter.\meaning##1X#1}{}%
       }{}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingUndefinedB{%
    \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingUndefinedB##1#1{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}%
      {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
      {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
       \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\escapechar=-1\relax
\expandafter\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined\expandafter{\string\undefined}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|\TeX abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{\TeX abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The empty sequence 
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The blank sequence  \verb*| |
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{ }{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence  \verb|\else|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{\else}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|{\UnDefIneD} abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{{\UnDefIneD} abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|{}\UnDefIneD abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{{}\UnDefIneD abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb*| \UnDefIneD abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{ \UnDefIneD abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|\UnDefIneD \fi \csname abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{\UnDefIneD \fi \csname abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

The sequence \verb|\UnDefIneD abc|
\CheckWhetherLeadingUndefined{\UnDefIneD abc}{does have}{does not have}
a leading token which is an undefined control sequence.

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach could be re-reading the entire input-file in question under verbatim-catcode-régime for checking via delimited arguments if the phrase `\commandtwo` is present. But this could be outmanoeuvred by having a comment containing that phrase.
In case of having input file A and input file B, both belonging to the same document and input file A being processed before processing input file B, this could within input file B also be outmanoeuvred by input file A containing `\let\foobar=\commandtwo` and input file B containing `\foobar` instead of `\commandtwo`.

Therefore I am not elaborating on this unless you write a comment which indicates that you are interested in this approach despite its shortcomings.